# Pandas Loop and Append Failure

Tags: python, loops, append

So I'm trying to send a datframe of VINs to the nhtsa open source api and get the information back.  The below works with replacing `df['vin']` with an actual vin.  However when adding the loop to my function and trying to append, the result is that I get a blank dataframe back instead of the information for the 12 or so VINs.  What am I doing wrong?

Code below:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests
    #develop the data
z = pd.DataFrame(columns = ["vin"], data = ['LHJLC79U58B001633','SZC84294845693987','LFGTCKPA665700387','L8YTCKPV49Y010001',
                                                 'LJ4TCBPV27Y010217','LFGTCKPM481006270','LFGTCKPM581004253','LTBPN8J00DC003107',
                                                 '1A9LPEER3FC596536','1A9LREAR5FC596814','1A9LKEER2GC596611','1A9L0EAH9C596099',
                                                 '22A000018'])

z['manufacturer'] = ['A','A','A','A','B','B','B','B','B','C','C','D','D']



def nhtsa(df):
    '''
    sends VIN to NHTSA for data call
    '''
    for i in df:
        url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/'
        post_fields = {'format': 'json', 'data': df['vin']};
        r = requests.post(url, data=post_fields);
        x = r.json()
        f = pd.DataFrame(x['Results'])
        g = f[['VIN','Make','Manufacturer','ManufacturerId','ManufacturerType', 'Model','ModelYear', 'ABS','VehicleType', 'BodyClass','DisplacementCC','ErrorCode', 'SuggestedVIN']]
        csv = pd.DataFrame()
        csv = csv.append(g, ignore_index = True)
        return csv

nhtsa(z)
```

Comment: In your function, you're looping through `for i in df`, but a) you're not doing anything with `i` inside the loop, which basically means `do this loop twice`, and b) `[i for i in z`] gives `['vin','manufacturer']`. What are you expecting to happen as you loop through your DF?

Comment: The vin is sent to the api and data about the vehicle is brought back, which I want to append to a data frame.

Comment: Do you understand what I said about the loop? `for i in df:` is going to be the strings `vin` and then `manufacturer`, which you never invoke in the loop. (Do you mean to pass in the values from the vin column instead? Then you declare a blank dataframe, and append to it, so you would never get more than one round of data returned anyway. My advice would be to make sure your function is doing what you want on one data point, then make sure it works in your loop, then put it in the function.

Comment: Maybe I’m missing it. Should it be for I in df[‘vin’]:  I’m not sure how to pass the vin in.

Comment: Have you tried some things to check your output? For example, test what you get out of `print([i for i in z])` vs `print([i for i in z['vin'])` and see how that compares to your expectations. The best advice I can give you is to program from the ground up: Get one thing to work how you expect, then start on another piece. I'd say there are a few issues with your function, and you may want to check and verify each step in the loop to see what it outputs

Comment: Thank you for the help. I know the api part works. I’ll start again

Comment: Hey @G.Anderson, I GOT IT!!!!!  I broke it down the way you said....printed after every line until I figured it out.  This is awesome!  Thanks so much.

Comment: Great work! Is that not the best feeling haha?

Answer (score 1):

Ok.  So, thanks to @G.Anderson, I figured this out.  First, the empty data frame should be outside of the loop.  Next, the i, as stated by G.Anderson was not getting called out.  I used a `.loc` statement to call what `i` is. Below is the code.

```
def nhtsa(df):
    '''
    sends VIN to NHTSA for data call
    '''
    df1 = pd.DataFrame()
    for i in current_trial.index:
        vin = df.loc[i, 'VIN']
        url = 'https://vpic.nhtsa.dot.gov/api/vehicles/DecodeVINValuesBatch/'
        post_fields = {'format': 'json', 'data': vin};
        r = requests.post(url, data=post_fields);
        x = r.json()
        f = pd.DataFrame(x['Results'])
        g = f[['VIN','Make','Manufacturer','ManufacturerId','ManufacturerType', 'Model','ModelYear', 'ABS','VehicleType', 'BodyClass','DisplacementCC','ErrorCode', 'SuggestedVIN']]
        df1 = df1.append(g)
    return df1
```

Comment: Thank you for updating with your fixed code, it may help someone else down the line and lots of folks don't follow through on this step